# openvpnserver not startted

Tags: openvpn

How can i solved the problem?

> "Options error: Parameter ca_file can only be specified in TLS-mode,
>   i.e. where --tls-server or --tls-client is also specified. "

Answer (score 1):

You should probably remove the parameter "ca_file" from your configuration, as the error message asks you to.